# Using files from google drive rather than uploading in colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, voice

I am following

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tzUmbS4lFP3xr6khSojg2vFCAx6xfW5r#scrollTo=EfkTM9TjUCRx

Real Time Voice Cloning.

I need help with Second section of this notebook where we have to record or upload file.
I have multiple files in my google drive which i have mounted in colab and want to use them rather than uploading same from pc ( which is very slow )

can anyone help me with solution for this code block ? like using wav/mp3 from our drive rather than uploading them via upload file button ?

want to change this code to use local files rather than uploading from pc :

```
#@title Run this cell to Record or Upload Audio
#@markdown * Either record audio from microphone or upload audio from file (.mp3 or .wav) 

SAMPLE_RATE = 22050
record_or_upload = "Upload (.mp3 or .wav)" #@param ["Record", "Upload (.mp3 or .wav)"]
record_seconds =   13111#@param {type:"number", min:219, max:10, step:3}

embedding = None
def _compute_embedding(audio):
  display(Audio(audio, rate=SAMPLE_RATE, autoplay=True))
  global embedding
  embedding = None
  embedding = encoder.embed_utterance(encoder.preprocess_wav(audio, SAMPLE_RATE))
def _record_audio(b):
  clear_output()
  audio = record_audio(record_seconds, sample_rate=SAMPLE_RATE)
  _compute_embedding(audio)
def _upload_audio(b):
  clear_output()
  audio = upload_audio(sample_rate=SAMPLE_RATE)
  _compute_embedding(audio)

if record_or_upload == "Record":
  button = widgets.Button(description="Record Your Voice")
  button.on_click(_record_audio)
  display(button)
else:
  #button = widgets.Button(description="Upload Voice File")
  #button.on_click(_upload_audio)
  _upload_audio("")
```

I have done :

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

then

`%cp -av "/content/drive/MyDrive/test.wav" "/content/"`

`test.wav` is copied now I want to use that directly rather than upload or record.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, you want to read the file directly from google Drive. Steps:

Mount google drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```

After that **cd** to the directory where you have the files:

```
curr_dir =  "/content/gdrive/My Drive/path/to/files/"
%cd "$curr_dir"
```

**My Drive** is the home directory of Google Drive (where you land when you open google drive). Then you can read files as if reading from a local drive.